# Where can I see code of python list under /usr/lib/python3.x?

Tags: python, list, implementation, cpython, pypy

Here I can see the source code of all the core modules of python like 'os', 'turtle', 'multiprocessing', 'argparse', … but I can't seem to locate the class definitions of builtin data structures like dict and list.
I tried

```
$ grep -r 'class list' .
./pydoc_data/topics.py:          '   the base class list; "__doc__" is the class’s documentation '
./pydoc_data/topics.py:             'class list([iterable])\n'
Binary file ./pydoc_data/__pycache__/topics.cpython-36.pyc matches
```

But found no 'class' implementation in this 'topics.py' file.

Comment: It's written in C, you can view the source on github https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: It's too broad repository. Can you help me navigate to the desired file?

Comment: Header file for list is here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d905df766c367c350f20c46ccd99d4da19ed57d8/Include/listobject.h

Comment: I can't comprehend it. Maybe I can get what I was originally searching for in PyPy's implementation?

Comment: I was originally looking for a .py file implementing Python's list class.

Comment: The pypy implementation is fairly heavy reading, good luck https://github.com/mozillazg/pypy/blob/c65f637a39f5e1a20e980689f17e0bf95a61ed21/pypy/objspace/std/listobject.py

Comment: Thanks a lot IainShelvington.
But as a student should I be wrapping my head around this 2000 lines of code or wait to learn some C and CPython to understand the CPython implementation?
Which will be better in the long run?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on data structures and algorithms in general if you are a student, similar designs will crop up. You do not need to know the exact workings of the Python list implementation.

Comment: Thanks Iain I found your advice to be reasonable and will follow accordingly. Thanks once again.

Comment: I guess your comment also meant that learning DSA will help me understand these implementations as well, if I try to some day?

Comment: Programming __is__ DSA, it will give you an understanding of almost any implementation if studied enough  (if you can read the language) although just knowing how something _may_ be implemented is usually enough, the beauty of open source